# MySQL - Varied query runtime for 'IN' Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance, sql-tuning, amazon-aurora

I have a table of about million rows and I am trying to filter out rows based on a particular column using an `IN` clause.

**Sample data:**

```
status
---------
'XXX-01'
'XXX-02'
'XXX-06'
'XXX-010'
'XX-XXX-027'
'XX-XXX-030'
```

**Query:**

The following query took about ***5 seconds*** to complete.

```
select * from demo_tabl where substring_index(status, '-', -1) in ('06', '07');
```

But the following took just a ***few milliseconds*** to complete.

```
select * from demo_tabl where substring_index(status, '-', -1) in ('06', '07', '030', '027');
```

The column is indexed, however, the index goes unused due to the `substring_index` function.

**Question:**

> Why is there a huge difference in the query runtime, in spite of the similar formation?

Comment: Are you measuring the time until the first row is returned or until all rows are returned?

Comment: I think you should use having clause with group by instead of where clause

Comment: Did you run each query, just once, in this order?  If so the data will be cached as a result of running the first query.  How many rows are returned in each case?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I was measuring it until limit 21

Comment: @rahulsm, my question is.. why the time difference?

Comment: @Ron Ballard, Same, as well as during different times.. observed the varied performance for both..

Comment: Run the first query 3 times. Run the second query 3 times. Then fist query again 3 times. Then second query again 3 times. Report the time it took to execute each of the 12 queries.

Comment: @jcaron, the time still applies the same, just as reported in the question..

Comment: @SathyasarathiGunasekaran so every single time the first query takes 5 seconds and the second one milliseconds? What does `EXPLAIN` report for each of the queries?

Comment: @jcaron The index is being used  using 'where' clause..

Comment: @SathyasarathiGunasekaran is the explain the same for both queries?

Comment: Yes, it is.. @jcaron

Comment: I don't see the `LIMIT 21`; what do you mean?  With `LIMIT 21`, the second query might stop a lot sooner due to finding lots of `030` early in the table!

Comment: which means even if i limited it to 21 entries.. the runtime still is the same